# Is mocking a direct function call on an object in Scala a code smell?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, dependency-injection

We currently use DI via function parameters for just about everything.  There's been a debate back and forth on our team about whether we would be better served calling the actual pure methods we are using directly from within a file rather than always injecting a dependency.  The argument is that this would reduce a lot of boilerplate in the main code and make it easier to track how different functions interact with eachother.

However, to support this while allowing unit testing, we would need to use something like ScalaMock to mock out static function calls.  Is this a good practice or a code smell?

Comment: How about using the argument as implicit? Or cake?

Answer (score 2):

Mocking a static function call is a code smell, but honestly mocking at all is a code smell. It may make sense to use mocks on a thin boundary layer where your application interfaces with an external library or service, but they should not be a first resort; most business logic tests should work with real objects. If your business logic involves invoking an external service, it's worth decoupling the expression of the logic from the actual external service calls, following something like http://michaelxavier.net/posts/2014-04-27-Cool-Idea-Free-Monads-for-Testing-Redis-Calls.html . That way there's no need to mock anything, except perhaps when testing the "interpreter" layer (which probably should have the redis connection passed in directly).